# java.lang.NullPointerException | try to get value from another class array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a game with a friend right now and I got some problems by implementing a save feature to the game. But I keep getting NullPointerExceptions every time I try to get a specific value from an array.

SaveGame.java:

```
public class SaveGame {
    static int newValue;
    //unnecessary stuff hidden...

    public static void SaveGame() {
        //The class which uses getTokenPositionList()
    }

    //Saves the positioning of the tokens within a String
    static String getTokenPositionList() {
        String tokenPositionList = "";
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                tokenPositionList = tokenPositionList + KodeKs.KodeKsData.getKodeKsData(row, col);
            }
        }
        return tokenPositionList;
    }  // end getTokenPositionList()
}
```

KodeKs.java:

```
public class KodeKs extends JPanel {
    public KodeKs() {
        //lots of unessecary stuff hidden
        public static class KodeKsData {
            public static int[][] board;
            public KodeKsData() {
                board = new int[10][10];
                setUpGame();
            }
            public static int getKodeKsData(int row, int col) {
                return board[row][col];

            }
            //more stuff hidden
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error-code I get when running this stuff:

> ```
> > Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> >     at KodeKs$KodeKsData.getKodeKsData(KodeKs.java:597)     at
> > SaveGame.getTokenPositionList(SaveGame.java:61)     at
> > SaveGame.SaveGame(SaveGame.java:33)     at
> > KodeKsToolBar$3.actionPerformed(KodeKsToolBar.java:48)  at
> > javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)  at
> > javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)  at
> > javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)  at
> > javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)   at
> > javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
> > Source)     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
> > javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)     at
> > java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)     at
> > java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)  at
> > java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> > java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> > Source)     at
> > java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> > Source)     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)   at
> > java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
> > java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
> > Source)     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
> > java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
> >     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
> >     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
> > Source)     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
> >     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
> > java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Comment: What line is 597 in `KodeKsData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared board array, but init it only in constructor, which is not called for static method call, declare it like:

`public static int[][] board = new int[10][10];`

also, consider - during static function call method "setupGame" is not called, is it expected?

Comment: Or use the static initializer `static { board = new int[10][10]; }`